# How can I play radio streaming in iPhone 5 to X versions in my website?

Tags: iphone, audio, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm working on a project for a client. It is a radio streaming, now it's working on multiple devices, for example: Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera, and for Android devices too. But the problem is that I can’t play from iPhone 5 to X versions.

Right now is working with HTML5 audio tag. I’ve been testing jPlayer to play for iPhone but not successful results.

How can I make it work?Or is there a script I can reproduce the streaming in iPhones? Here is the sample of the radio station:

https://codepen.io/fendercat/pen/zyZWBQ

```
<div id="player">
  <div id="player-controles">
    <audio id="player_html5" autoplay="" src="http://162.210.196.145:37747/;">Nombre de la Estación</audio>
      <!-- Botones de control de audio -->
      <div class="areaPlayer">
        <a class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById(&#39;player_html5&#39;).play();">
          <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById(&#39;player_html5&#39;).pause();">
          <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById(&#39;player_html5&#39;).volume += 0.1;">
          <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById(&#39;player_html5&#39;).volume -= 0.1;">
          <i class="fa fa-volume-down"></i>
        </a>
      </div><!-- /.areaPlayer -->

      <script>
        // Volume Inicial player HTML5
        document.getElementById("player_html5").volume=1.0;
      </script> 
    </div><!-- /#player-controles -->
  </div><!-- /#player -->
```

The codepen shows a little light gray player with 4 controls (play, pause, volume up and volume down).